# google api contacts php simplexml

Tags: php, api, simplexml, contacts

I am looking to fetch the contact's first name from google contacts without any luck. However, I am able to extract the email address no problem. Can someone show me what i am doing wrong?

```
$xmlresponse=file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?oauth_token='.$accesstoken);
//reading xml using SimpleXML
$xml=  new SimpleXMLElement($xmlresponse);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');

$nameFirst = $xml->xpath('//gd:givenName'); // I have also tried //gd:name
$result = $xml->xpath('//gd:email');

foreach($nameFirst as $nameF){
echo $nameF->getName();
}
foreach ($result as $title) {
echo $title->attributes()->address . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the XML file? How is the element named that contains the first name?

Comment: Yes, I have and its named gd:name and I have tried that but i thought if you use // you can jump directly to gd:givenName. If I am not correct than why would it work for gd:email?

Answer (score 5):

The XML I got from the Google Contacts API was mixed, the name was the node value of a normal XML node "title" but the email was a parameter in a `gdata` tag `gd:email`.  Given the possibility of multiple email addresses I used the following to extract an array of single name/email pairs:

```
$req = new Google_HttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/property-email/");
$val = $this->client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody());
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');

$output_array = array();
foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) {
  foreach ($entry->xpath('gd:email') as $email) {
    $output_array[] = array((string)$entry->title, (string)$email->attributes()->address);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The example above (from google client api examples) does not work for emails. I tried a lot and for me the response contains other information but not emails.
I found a google  [group's discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-contacts-api/U63UnuqfMoA) where they talk about that, seems to be a bug where simplexml doesn't see some gd: information.

I used simpleXMLElements and xpath as Claude did, but also for me I can get only emails.

Comment: Do you have a link to that topic?

Comment: Yes, [basic links](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-contacts-api/U63UnuqfMoA) @bvanvelsen

Answer (score 0):

There's [a PHP client-side library that Google supplies](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) for interacting with the various services it offers. Contacts is one of them.

The example code for contacts service uses the trick of json encoding and decoding the result:

```
require_once '../../src/apiClient.php';
session_start();

$client = new apiClient();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Contacts PHP Sample');
$client->setScopes("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/");
// Documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/basics.html
// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=contacts to generate your
// oauth2_client_id, oauth2_client_secret, and register your oauth2_redirect_uri.
// $client->setClientId('insert_your_oauth2_client_id');
// $client->setClientSecret('insert_your_oauth2_client_secret');
// $client->setRedirectUri('insert_your_redirect_uri');
// $client->setDeveloperKey('insert_your_developer_key');

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
 $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
  $client->revokeToken();
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $req = new apiHttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
  $val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);

  // The contacts api only returns XML responses.
  $response = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody()));
  print "<pre>" . print_r(json_decode($response, true), true) . "</pre>";

  // The access token may have been updated lazily.
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $auth = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

if (isset($auth)) {
    print "<a class=login href='$auth'>Connect Me!</a>";
  } else {
    print "<a class=logout href='?logout'>Logout</a>";
}
```

Comment: Can someone give me an example of how I can retrieve data because google does not have example for contacts for some reason.

Comment: Claude, I thought the problem you were having was not retrieving, but parsing.  ??  You have actually retrieved the data, correct?  The example above shows how they parse it.